# How to pass variable of type ArrayOfString to Apex function?

Tags: apex, wsdl2apex

I have an Apex class generated from a WSDL. There is a function in the class that takes an `ArrayOfString` object as input. For testing, how can I assign a value to a variable of type `ArrayOfString`?

I have the variable declared as:

```
soaNrccuaOrgOms.ArrayOfString saleNumbers= new soaNrccuaOrgOms.ArrayOfString();
```

and the function is called as:

```
Boolean result = obj.TipOrderStatusUpdate(saleNumbers);
```

Comment: If you open up the generated Apex class soaNrccuaOrgOms, you should find an inner class called ArrayOfString, this itself will have members you need to set before passing your 'saleNumbers' variable to the TipOrderStatusUpdate method.

Answer (score 1):

If you open up the generated Apex class soaNrccuaOrgOms, you should find an inner class called ArrayOfString, this itself will have members you need to set before passing your 'saleNumbers' variable to the TipOrderStatusUpdate method.